# $\int_0^5 \frac{dx}{x^2-x-2}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, partial-fractions

I am having some difficulty with this problem. I am getting a finite answer but when I put the equation into wolfram alpha to check my answer it says that the integral does not converge.Here is what I have tried to do so far:

$$\int_0^5 \frac{dx}{x^2-x-2} \\
\int_0^5 \frac{dx}{x^2-x-2} = \int_0^5 \frac{1}{x^2-x-2}dx = \int_0^5 \frac{1}{(x+2)(x-1)}dx = \int_0^5 \frac{A}{(x+2)}dx + \int_0^5 \frac{B}{(x-1)}dx \\
\text{Find A, let x = -2} \\
1 = A(x-1) + B(x+2) \\
1 = -3A \\
A = -1/3 \\
\text{Find B, let x = 1}\\
 1 = A(x-1) + B(x+2) \\
1 = 3B \\
B = 1/3 \\
\text{Rewrite the original integral as a product pulling the 1/3 out of the integral} \\
\frac{1}{3} [-\int_0^5 \frac{1}{x + 2} + \int_0^5 \frac{1}{x - 1}] \\
\frac{1}{3} [-\int_0^5 \frac{1}{u}du + \int_0^5 \frac{1}{w}dw] \\
\text{Change the bounds on the integral} \\
\text{u = 5 + 2 = 7, u = 0 + 2 = 2} \\
\text{w = 5 - 1 = 4, w= 0 - 1 = -1} \\
\frac{1}{3} [-\ln\lvert u\rvert \lvert_2^7  + \ln\lvert w\rvert \lvert_{-1}^{4} ] \\
\text{Re substitute our u and w values} \\
\frac{1}{3} [-\ln\lvert x + 2\rvert \lvert_2^7  + \ln\lvert x - 1\rvert \lvert_{-1}^{4} ] \\
 \frac{1}{3} [-(\ln(9) - \ln(4)) + \ln(3)-\ln(2)] \\
\frac{1}{3} [-0.41] \\
-1.33$$

Comment: It’s an improper integral: the integrand is undefined at $x=2$. (Your factorization isn’t quite right: it should be $(x+1)(x-2)$.)

Comment: It is actually $(x-2)(x+1)$, and there is a bad singularity at $x=2$.

Comment: you substituted u and w and found new limits of integration.  Then you substuted back and did not change your limits.  Either apply your limits in terms of u and w.  Or don't bother finding the limits in u and w and solve everything in terms of x.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But *how bad is it*?!? :)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Bad enough to deserve noticing at the least.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: Like $\frac{1}{t}$ at $0$, so roughly just bad enough.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 apocalyptically bad.  We have finally found the singularity we all feared would one day be found.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Nah, that singularity was already found.

Comment: Thanks guys ahhh such a silly mistake. Shouldn't it still converge to a real number though? even if the bounds are different wont I get ln|u|, which will be positive. Then if ln is positive I will get a finite number. Unless the function itself has to be continuous meaning a discontinuity at 2 makes it not converge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this misconception is simply found when you try to look at the graph of the function.

[Graph here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/twhbca0vyq)

You will note that over the region $0\le x\le5$, you cross a point where the function diverges to $\pm\infty$, which is what Wolfram|Alpha was noting.